# How to release or distribute an application that uses mikro-orm?

Tags: mikro-orm

In the configuration I have to specify the paths to .js and .ts files defining entities:

```
MikroORM.init({
    ...
    entitiesDirs: ["build/entities"],
    entitiesDirsTs: ["src/entities"],
});
```

So, when I will go to release or distribute the application. Will I need distribute the typescript code too? or will I need distribute only the cache generated? or will I need distribute both? or... none?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## As of MikroORM v2.2

Now you can work with default metadata provider, it will require entity source files only if you do not provide `entity` or `type` options in your decorators (you can use `entity` callback to use reference to entity class instead of using string name in `type`, handle for refactoring via IDE like webstorm).

## Original answer:

You should ship the typescript code too, and let the cache regenerate on the server - cache would be rebuilt anyway as it checks absolute path to cached entity for invalidation.

You could implement your own cache adapter or metadata provider to get around this, if you don't want to ship the typescript code.

This is how you could implement custom metadata provider that simply throws error when the type option is missing:

```
import { MetadataProvider, Utils } from 'mikro-orm';
import { EntityMetadata } from 'mikro-orm/dist/decorators';

export class SimpleMetadataProvider extends MetadataProvider {

  async loadEntityMetadata(meta: EntityMetadata, name: string): Promise<void> {
    // init types and column names
    Object.values(meta.properties).forEach(prop => {
      if (prop.entity) {
        prop.type = Utils.className(prop.entity());
      } else if (!prop.type) {
        throw new Error(`type is missing for ${meta.name}.${prop.name}`)
      }
    });
  }

}
```

Then provide this class when initializing:

```
const orm = await MikroORM.init({
  // ...
  metadataProvider: SimpleMetadataProvider,
});
```

The value of `type` should be JS types, like `string/number/Date`... You can observe your cached metadata to be sure what values should be there.

Also keep in mind that without TS metadata provider, you will need to specify entity type in @ManyToOne decorator too (either via `entity` callback, or as a string via `type`).

Comment: The "Property" decorator has an option "type" (I'm not sure if is for the DB data type or for the JS data type). Can't be it used to specify the data type and avoid generation from Typescript source code?

Comment: Nope, that wouldnt be enough. Take a look at https://github.com/B4nan/mikro-orm/blob/master/lib/metadata/TypeScriptMetadataProvider.ts . This is what happens by default, but you could provide custom implementation to achieve what you want, or use JS metadata provider https://b4nan.github.io/mikro-orm/usage-with-js/

Comment: take a look at updated answer how to use custom metadata provider. i will probably add this into the project somehow in near future, its a valid point that not everyone wants to ship TS code, i just need to think about the best approach, but you should be good with this custom provider in the mean time.

Comment: Wow! Thanks you very much. I am not sure if `optionalDependencies` in `package.json` can be used with Typescript, but if you add this to project one possibility can be: If `typescript` and `ts-morph` are installed use `TypeScriptMetadataProvider` by default. If only `typescript` is installed use `SimpleMetadataProvider` by default. If none are installed use `JavaScriptMetadataProvider` by default. I think this too permit left out `typescript` and `ts-morph` of the `dependencies` in `package.json` to get more popularity of Vanilla JS developers. (I hope I'm not saying nonsense)

Comment: I think it is fine to keep those deps as they are now. This is server side package, so it is not a big deal to have extra deps that are not used. I will think about that feature detection you proposed, sounds reasonable, but I would need to add proper validation and error messages so one can easily tell what and why happens under the hood.

Comment: It could be even simpler, without introducing new provider, just improving the TS one so it only requires entity source file when there is a real need for it (e.g. type or entity decorator options are not provided).

Comment: Another possible solution, more comfortable but maybe little solid. Use relative routes in the cache and don't regenerate it if `NODE_ENV=production` (save de cache by default in "build" path, getting the path from `MikroORM.init({ ..., entitiesDirs: ["build/entities"], ...})`)

Comment: Just released v2.2, with improved TS metadata provide, that should be working for you (it requires TS source files only when you don't provide `entity` or `type` options in your decorators).